# Add reference of .net 4.5 class library project to .net core 2.1 project

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-core, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to add reference of .net 4.5 class library project to .net core 2.1 project.There are no compile time errors but at the run time it shows **FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq'**. I have used System.Data.Linq inside the .net 4.5 project.

Comment: .NET Core can't *reliably* consume .NET Framework libraries (if at all); you really want a .NET Standard or .NET Core library (you should prefer .NET Standard by default)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [referencing .NET framework 4 dll in .NET core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703060/referencing-net-framework-4-dll-in-net-core-2-0)

Comment: It's not about versions, so whether it's Framework 4.0 or 4.5 and Core 2.0 or 2.1 is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarcGravell  Noted & thanks