# Is it possible to do a .NET Core DLL containing .NET Core Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Is it possible to create a .NET Core DLL which contains the other .NET Core Framework DLLs in order to be run without installing the .NET Core?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is why VS has a publish option which create a setup.exe like commercial software.  The setup.exe installs the dlls so code will run on machines that do not have Net.

Comment: You mean a self-contained application? This should already be possible. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use .net core with legacy .net framework dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260792/use-net-core-with-legacy-net-framework-dlls)

Comment: There is no such thing as .NET Core Framework. There is .NET Framework (and Runtime) and .NET Core (and Runtime). Edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core 3 supports [single-file executables](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/) that contain all framework specific assemblies, resources, content files and other stuff that the app requires to run:

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x86 -c release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

[Self-contained deployments (SCD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) are supported in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you are looking for is called Self-contained deployment and is possible with .NET Core, but not .NET Framework.

See more here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd