# System.BadImageFormatException error when using .net framework dll with .net 5

Tags: c#, .net

As the titles indicates, I'm trying to use a third-party dll compiled for .net framework.

I'm using Avalonia UI with .net 5.

Unfortunately I'm getting a "System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly".

Exception triggers whenever my class's method (which contains a call to a dll method) is called.

```
class MainClass
{
    void MainMethod()
    {
        MyService.ServiceMethod(); <== Exception triggers here
    }
}
class MyService
{
    public static void ServiceMethod()
    {
        ThirdPartyMethod();
    }
}
```

I thought it was possible to use a .net framework dll in core as long as the library didn't use windows specific API ([Use .net core with legacy .net framework dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260792/use-net-core-with-legacy-net-framework-dlls))

I've analyzed the dll with dotnet portability analyzer (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConnieYau.NETPortabilityAnalyzer) which returned a 100% score with .net core 3.1.

I've tried messing with build target architectures (x64, x86) to no avail.

Is the dll straight-up incompatible? Can I do anything without the sources? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the third party dll compiled for 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: There's one .dll for each architecture and I tried using both in different configurations